# How reliable is spark stream join with static databricks delta table

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

In the databricks [there is a cool feature](https://dustinvannoy.com/2021/06/09/spark-streaming-delta-lookup/) that allows to join a streaming dataframe with a delta table. The cool part is that changes in the delta table are still reflected for a subsequent join results. It works just fine, but I'm curious to know how this works, and what are the limitations here? e.g. what's the expected update delay? How it changes as the delta table grows? Is it safe to rely on it in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on this feature (it's really of Spark) - many customers are using it in production. Regarding the other questions - there are multiple aspects here, depending on factors, like, how often table updates, etc.:

- Because static Delta table isn't cached it's re-read on each join - depending on the cluster configuration, it may not be very bad if you use [Delta Caching](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/delta-cache.html), so files aren't re-downloaded every time, only new data will be re-downloaded.
- Read performance could be affected if you have a lot of small files, etc. - it depends on how you're writing into that table & if you do things like OPTIMIZE.
- Depending on how often the Delta table is updated, you can cache it & periodically refresh it

But really to answer it completely, you need to provide more information specific to your code, use case, etc.

Comment: Great insight. Question. If I'm not using a Delta caching, can I get the OOM issues too? (Because everytime the table is updated or new stream data comes in, it tried to re-read the whole data?)

Comment: I don't think so, but it really depends on multiple factors so it's hard to say without understanding what you're doing

Comment: For delta caching, can I use it on the local mode spark?
1. `spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "true")`
2. `spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE my_table2
USING DELTA
LOCATION 's3a://MY_DELTA_PATH';
""")`
3. 
`import time
s = time.time()
spark.sql("select count(*) from my_table2").show()
print(time.time() - s)`

But '3.' shows same time taken...which means, cache doesn't work?

Comment: you can see hits/misses in the Spark UI. But for Delta, `count(*)` is a metadata operation as it can take row count directly from the Delta transaction log without reading data

Comment: Changed count(*) --> * but still same result. It would be glad to see some examples of caching!

Comment: look into Spark SQL plan in the Spark UI - at bottom you should see data about hits/misses